# Constricting a span tag to match another spans width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to eliminate any overflow from a span that isn't matching another.

This is what I'm dealing with. http://jsfiddle.net/D2WPW/12/

So the `.graph span` isn't matching the `.text span`'s width. I thought `overflow: hidden;` would do the trick. I guess not. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Any insight and help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A span tag will take up as much room as needed.  If you look closely you are inserting a canvas element in `.graph` with an inline style that explicitly sets the width to 116px.

Perhaps instead you should make the width of the canvas element dynamic and set it equal to the width of the adjacent `.text` span.

Answer (score 0):

The `.text` elements are not inside the `.graph` elements, so there's no reason that `overflow: hidden` on `.graph` should clip `.text`.

What you should be doing is setting a static width as well as `overflow: hidden` and `text-align: justify` on the elements which contain both the graphs and the texts: http://jsfiddle.net/D2WPW/26/

You will probably also want `white-space: nowrap` to prevent too-long text from wrapping to the next line.